# LESS Nested Properties

Tags: css, sass, less

Out of curiosity:

Are Nested Properties possible in LESS? Since SASS supports this feature ([Nested Properties](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#nested_properties))

```
div {
  background: {
    size: cover;
    color: green;
  }
}
```

TO

```
div {
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, it seems it is not possible.
But you could easily create a mixin [that works similar](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-named-parameters).

```
.setBackground( @color: green; @image: ''; @repeat: no-repeat; @position: center; @size: '' ) {
  background: @color @repeat @position;

  & when not ( @image = '' ) {
    background-image: @image;
  }

  & when not ( @size = '' ) {
    background-size: @size;
  }
}

div {
  .setBackground(
    @color: yellow;
    @image: url( some-image.png );
    @repeat: repeat;
    @size: cover;
  );
}
```